# functional xml building in scala

Tags: xml, scala, functional-programming

What's the best way to take a document with arbitrary text formatting, say:

```
Hello world

1.1.1 (John Doe)

Paragraph one here... pargraph one continued here

paragraph two here
```

and convert it into an XML document that looks something like this:

```
<note id="1.1.1" author_first = "John" author_last = "Doe">
  <paragraph>Paragraph one here... paragraph one continued here</paragraph>
  <paragraph>paragraph two here</paragraph>
</note>
```

The only thing I can think of is the standard imperative way of using an `XMLBuilder` type class was say a `Scanner`. But that doesn't seem very much like idiomatic Scala.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already parsed the data, you could just go with the literal approach...

```
val paragraphs: List[String] = ...
val noteId: String = ...
val authorName: (String, String) = ...

<note id={noteId} author_first={authorName._1} author_last={authorName._2}>
  {paragraphs.map(s => <paragraph>{s}</paragraph>)}
</note>
```

Comment: Note that if you haven't already parsed the data, there are a variety of ways to do that, none of which involve XML. :)